# Media is not playing in iOS phonegap 1.5 app

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, media

I am developing iOS app using phonegap 1.5. In this app I am using phonegap's Media API to play mp3 files. But it's not working on iOS. Same codebase works on Android without any issue.

**Code:**

**Audio.js**

```
 //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;
function playAudio(src) {
        //alert("inside");
        //if (my_media == null) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            //alert(my_media);
        //} // else play current audio
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
        //alert("Played");
    }

      function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

I am including Audio.js in my html file and then calling function

`playAudio("audio/welcome.mp3");`

All of my mp3 files reside in **www/audio** folder.

I debugged using alert statements, call comes till this line of code
`my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);`

No error callback or no errors in console of xcode.

Am I missing something here? What could be the issue?

Comment: It looks like the path issue.have you created a group(Xcode) "audio" or is it a folder inside www folder.

Comment: It is a folder inside www folder.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is pretty difficult with having stuff behaving differently that it should, especially when it comes to media and plugins. You need to have something that changes the file path based off of the device (using the Cordova Device Plugin):

```
//Gets Device Platform
document.addEventListener("deviceready", getDevicePlatform, false);
function getDevicePlatform() {
    $scope.devicePlatform = device.platform;
    console.log(device.platform);
}
```

Then to set the media player file path correctly:

```
if ($scope.devicePlatform == "Android") {
            var songFilePath = '/android_asset/www/res/' + song.name + '.mp3';
        }
        else {
            var songFilePath = 'res/' + song.name + '.mp3';
        }

        $scope.song = new Media(songFilePath);
```

The song .name is something special I had to dynamically get the path, but the main thing is that for Android devices you need the /android_asset/, but for other devices like iOS and PhoneGap you can use normal file paths to media inside the /www folder.